# in messaging system i don't know how to view message

Tags: php, mysql

i am new in php i want to know how to view message

this is my code

```
$idto = $_GET['id'];
$query2 = mysql_query("select * from users where id =".$idto." ");
$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2);
echo "<b><font size='6' face='Comic Sans MS'><center>".$row2['firstname']."</center></font></b><br><br>";


$query2 = mysql_query("select * from message  where id_from =".$idto."  and id_to =". $_SESSION['id']." ORDER BY id");
$query1 = mysql_query("select * from message  where id_to =".$idto."  and id_from =". $_SESSION['id']." ORDER BY id");
```

i select message send by user1 & by user 2 but i dont know how to view them correctly 
when i use  this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2) ) 
{


echo'<fieldset style="width:250" align="center">';
echo"<legend><b>".$row2['firstname']."</b></legend>";
echo $row['message'];
echo "<br>";
echo $row['date'];
echo"<hr>";
echo"</fieldset>";


}



while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1) ) 
{




echo'<fieldset style="width:250" align="center">';
echo"<legend><b>".$_SESSION['firstname']."</b></legend>";
echo $row1['message'];
echo "<br>";
echo $row1['date'];
echo"<hr>";
echo"</fieldset>";




}
```

it view messages but in incorrectly way 
can any one help me please thanks :) 
if you dont understand what i am saying 
i mean i want to know how to view message

Comment: What errors are being thrown in PHP? It looks like you have an erro on line 2 with your concatenation.

Comment: no errors just i want to know how to view them in correctly way

Comment: Do you mean you want to view your messages in a specific order?

Comment: yes i want to view message like facebook twitter user1 then user 2 then user1 then user 2

Comment: Change your ORDER BY clause to ASC (ascending) or DESC (descending) for whatever column you want to order.

Comment: can you tell me how because i am new in php

Comment: i want to view the both columns user 1 and user 2 ASC by the time  they send in

Answer (score 0):

Firstly switch from mysql_* to mysqli_* because mysql_* functions are deprecated.

To order your queries in ascending order:

```
$query1 = mysql_query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM message 
    WHERE id_to = ".$idto." 
    AND id_from = ".$_SESSION['id']." 
    ORDER BY id ASC
");

$query2 = mysql_query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM message 
    WHERE id_from = ".$idto." 
    AND id_to = ".$_SESSION['id']." 
    ORDER BY id ASC
");
```

Comment: it's not what i mean but thanks for tying i mean i want to view them mixed like facebook messaging system